# After a server upgrade, what types of health checks do you perform

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, solution-package, testing

We are currently trying to validate a deployment but want to make sure we've checked all the appropriate things. Other than testing new functionality, what steps to do you take to make sure an update or code deployment is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my experience, I would do the following things.

- functionality testing of the solution
- use developer dashboard to measure the performance of the page loading.
- perform other basic testing on the sites to verify that solution did not hurt anything else i.e create list, creating workflows, send alerts etc
- check the ULS logs and event logs if any suspicious activity
- make sure your deployed solution is deployed to proper place, i.e if it is web app scoped then deployed to web app only.